# How to setup Google Translate API for Node.js?

Tags: node.js, google-translate

I want to use Googles Cloud Translation API in my Node.js application, however I'm getting a `The request is missing a valid API key.` error.

I have followed the [Quickstart guide](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-usage-nodejs) provided by Google.

I have created GCP project, downloaded the private key as JSON file and setup the environment variable in Powershell ([img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNNSW.jpg)).

After that I've installed the library with 
`yarn add @google-cloud/translate`

The code I'm running in my `translate.js` file comes from the Quickstart guide with additional `try-catch` blocks:

```
async function quickstart(
  projectId = process.env.PROJECT_ID // Project Id from JSON file
) {
  try {
    // Imports the Google Cloud client library
    const { Translate } = require('@google-cloud/translate');
    // Instantiates a client
    const translate = new Translate({ projectId });

    // The text to translate
    const text = 'Hello, world!';

    // The target language
    const target = 'ru';

    // Translates some text into Russian
    const [translation] = await translate.translate(text, target);
    console.log('Text:', text);
    console.log('Translation:', translation);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

quickstart();
```

When I then run `node translate.js`, I'll get an Error:

```
{ Error: The request is missing a valid API key.
   ...

  code: 403,
  errors:
   [ { message: 'The request is missing a valid API key.',
       domain: 'global',
       reason: 'forbidden' } ],
  response: undefined,
  message: 'The request is missing a valid API key.' }
```

I am on Windows 10, Node v10.13.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Believe you would have missed this environment variable defining , before starting the node service

Replace [PATH] with the file path of the JSON file that contains your service account key, and [FILE_NAME] with the filename.

With PowerShell:

```
$env:GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[PATH]"

For example:

$env:GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="C:\Users\username\Downloads\[FILE_NAME].json"
```

Comment: I have done this before running node. see here: https://imgur.com/a/0ZdVVhB

Comment: $env:GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="C:\Users\username\Downloads\[FILE_NAME].json"; node yourappstartupfile.js

Comment: The above command sets the env variable and immediately start the program usng semicolon. Tis is a powerbuild related command.

Comment: Yes, just tested it. Thanks!